# iOS : I can't find my file?

Tags: objective-c, ios, file, path, nsfilemanager

I have this arborescence:

```
Project Folder
      build
      Project
      ProjectTests
      Pictures
```

In the sub-folder "Project" I have the AppDelegate and a file called "Alert.txt". I want to access that text file from my AppDelegate so I tried :

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"test");
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: @"Alert.txt" ] == YES)
        NSLog(@"good");

}
```

Of course it prints "test", but not "good". What is the correct path ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the path to your file use

```
NSString * myFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Alert" ofType:@"txt"];    
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: myFile ])
    NSLog(@"good");
```

Comment: I guess you were meaning `fileExistsAtPath:myFile`. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Yes sorry, you are welcome :) i will update the answer, pleas also dont forget to accept the answer if it was useful cheers :)

Comment: I'll do it as soon as I'm allowed to. ;) Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

`NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Alert" ofType:@"txt];`